# How to express p(y|x) in terms of p(x,y)?

Tags: probability, integral

Given two inter-dependent random variables $X$, $Y$ with a joint probability density p(x,y),  can we express the conditional probability $p(y|x)$ in terms of the integral of something related to $p(x,y)$?

Comment: An integral like that can do in the denominator of the conditional distribution ratio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The question is looking very much like an homework assignment...**

The joint probability for {x,y} can be expressed as:
$$
p(x,y) = p(x) \times p(y|x)
$$

This can rewritten as:

$$
p(y|x)=\frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)}
$$

Use this with the probability density function $p(x)$ expressed as a marginal probability density function:
$$p(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}p(x,y)dy$$

Answer (score 2):

It is expressed by the usual formation:

$p(y|x)*p(x) = p(x,y)$

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution#Continuous_distributions).